# Flask + Mongo Multi-tenant app

Tags: python, flask, flask-mongoengine

I am trying to build an app with multiple database for each client.
With flask-mongoengine you can register multiple database connection and use the alias to connect to the database at the time of query ORM models. I am using `@before_request` hook to set the tenant.

```
app.config["MONGODB_SETTINGS"] = {
    'db': 'default',
    'host': 'mongodb://localhost/default',
    'alias': 'default'
},
{
    'db': 'client1',
    'host': 'mongodb://localhost/client1',
    'alias': 'client1'
}

from models.import Purchase
def get_data():
    with switch_db(Purchase, g.context['tenant']) as Data:
        record = Data.objects(pk=<id>).first()
        return record
```

I am able to switch the database successfully with this approach.

I want to switch the context of the database globally or at the time of user chooses client. So that I don't have to change it for each method and every time I have to query.